Parquet column cannot be converted in file <parquet path> Column: [year], Expected: int, Found: INT64
I have a large number of small parquets. 80% of them have year column encoded as int, but 20% as 'Int64'
I read them by specifying schema, where I specify year column as IntegerType.
df = spark.read.schema(myschema).parquet('gs://path/myfiles/')

But when I attempt to write df:
df.write.parquet('gs://myresults/')

I get the error:

Parquet column cannot be converted in file  Column: [year], Expected: int, Found: INT64

I've tried explicit casting:
df = df.select(col('year').cast(IntegerType))  
df.write.parquet('gs://myresults/')

I still get this error.
How can I avoid this casting error?

Find below a quick sample data to test and observe the precision loss when cast(IntegerType) is applied on a LongType data type column (e.g. 300000000000000001 is 413007873 after casting in example below).
One approach is to:

Define the year column data type as LongType in the schema when reading the parquet files.
Filter out rows where year is greater than max IntegerType allowed (e.g. 2147483647) and, perhaps, save them to an error table for postmortem analysis.
Apply cast(IntegerType) function and write the data.

--- CODE ---
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, LongType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

data = [("A","B",300000000000000001), ("C","D",4001), ("E","F",4002)]

schema = StructType([StructField("firstname",StringType(),True), StructField("lastname",StringType(),True), StructField("salary", LongType(), True)])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
df.printSchema()
df = df.withColumn("salary",df.salary.cast(IntegerType()))
df.printSchema()
df.show()

--- OUTPUT ---
root
 |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- salary: long (nullable = true)

root
 |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- salary: integer (nullable = true)

+---------+--------+---------+
|firstname|lastname|   salary|
+---------+--------+---------+
|        A|       B|413007873|
|        C|       D|     4001|
|        E|       F|     4002|
+---------+--------+---------+

--- REFERENCES ---

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html


Thank you for the reply, and your post makes sense, but. I know for a fact that in my case values in the year column will be lower than 9999, and never approach the integer limit of 2147483647 :)
